# One-to-many two-way communication in simulink

Tags: design-patterns, simulink

I have a simulink model where I have multiple blocks (children) which needs to send and receive signals with one common block (parent) and send one signal to another (listener).

[image: Simulink]

The question is: are there any good design patterns for this?

Comment: Well if you are seeking for a stylish form, use GOTO and FROM with local variables, and background colour them, that makes the simulink structure way less messy.

Comment: @AnderBiguri: Thanks, I think that is the best solution. But I would like to have a more robust and simpler solution (e.g., not need to change tags for each block).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use busses to transfer the information throughout the model. Make each child subsystem have only one bus output (you can use [Bus Creator](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/simulink/slref/buscreator.html) blocks), then combine all 4 busses into one, and select the appropriate signals for the parent and listener subsystems with [Bus Selector](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/simulink/slref/busselector.html) blocks. Similarly, make the parent subsystem output a bus, and select the approriate signals for each of the child inputs. It takes a bit more work to set-up but is the more robust, scalable and "elegant" way to go about this in my mind.

Arnaud

Comment: But also less readable. A better way is to create the bus just outside the child, and "explode" it again just before You enter the parent or listener. This way the advantage of buses creating less mess, but avid the disadvantage of buses, that You cannot see whats in them. 

That is: child -> all signals -> bus creator -> bus -> bus selector -> all signals -> parrent.